# Passing value from typescript to sass

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm creating a progress circle in sass, but I have to set his percent in typescript. So in sass how can assign to it?

So my html:

```
    <ion-range class="circular-progress" min="40" max="200" step="1" pin="true" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="rate">.......
.................
```

Now in sass I have this variable :

```
$percent-to-show
```

And it need just a number. The number in html is `{{rate}}` so I need to assign it to the variable in sass.So I can send it form typescript or html. But I don't know how to do it .

I'm using **typescript**.
My class is this :

```
.circular-progress {
  //circular-progress function
  //circular-progress($maxPercent, $percent, $color-bar, $color-back);
  background: circular-progress(100, $percent-to-show, #03A9F4, #E0E0E0);

  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all .3s linear;

  &::before {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: rgba(black,.54);
    content: '#{$percent-to-show}%';
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(.87);
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I want to put a number in `$percent-to-show`

Comment: SASS is a preprocessor. There is no SASS in a running application.

Comment: So is not way to do what I want to achive?

Comment: SASS creates plain CSS. You want to set the appropriate CSS style. Maybe you can post the line from your SASS file.

Comment: You can add a style attribute to your HTML and edit that with JS

Comment: @YounesM I'm using typescript

Comment: @zeroflagL ok now im editing.

Comment: You can still use plain JS in Typescript files since typescript compiles into javascript.